# Returning max value of array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return the max value of an array in JavaScript without using the [`Math.max`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp) function. Is [`reduce`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) a good way to do this? My problem is that it is returning `5` not `11` like I want it to. Am I going about this the *best* way? Could somebody guide me in the right direction.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function max(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (prev.value >= curr.value) ? prev : curr;
  });
}

console.log(
  max([3, 1, 2, 7, 11, 3, 4, 5])
);
```

Comment: Can't you just `.sort()` the array?

Comment: Remove `.value`--you're just comparing a bunch of `undefined`s here. Don't `sort`, it's slower than `reduce`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer OP said no using Math.max()

Comment: If someone drops by for the title only: `Math.max(...[3, 1, 2, 7, 11, 3, 4, 5])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of your array are not objects (so, they don't have property `value` which you attempt to evaluate) those are plain numbers, so you may compare each array item with `reduce()` aggregated parameter directly:

```js
const arr = [3, 1, 2, 7, 11, 3, 4, 5],
      arrMax = arr => arr.reduce((max,n) => n > max ? n : max)
      
console.log(arrMax(arr))
```

Comment: Essentially the reduce function starts at `arr[0]` and compares to max (`n > max`). If `n > max` is true, `n` is returned (`? n`) as the new max. If not, `max` is retained as the maximum (`: max`). Then it repeats this for `arr[1]`, then `arr[2]` until it gets to the end. @ggorlen Hope this explains it...

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` is the best way to go IMHO but you can still use `Math.max` to find the biggest number out of the two.

Here's a `max` function with parameters destructuring so you can do `max(10, 42)` instead of `max([10, 42])` which is closer to the `Math.max` signature.

```js
const max = (...xs) =>
  xs.reduce((max, x) => Math.max(max, x));
  
console.log(max(3, 1, 2, 7, 11, 3, 4, 5));
//=> 11
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the best way is to just `sort` the array and return the first or last value of the array

```js
  function compare(a , b) {
      return  b - a
  }
  let sortedArray = unSortedArray.sort(compare)
  console.log(sortedArray[0])
```

Comment: There's no reason to use sort (at best O(n log n)) when you can determine this in linear time.

Comment: This also mutates the original array.

Comment: I think the result should be consistent with `Math.max`. With the following array `[10, NaN]`, you would return `10` whereas `Math.max(10, NaN)` would return `NaN`.